# MSACCESS query: not part of an aggregate function

Tags: ms-access, expression, aggregate

MSACCESS query:

I have an append query that pulls fields from 2 tables (Right Join).  I want to add an expression that multiplies a value in one field by a value on a form. The query works fine, until I add the calculated expression, but the error is that another (unrelated) field is not part of an aggregate function.  If I remove that field, it will complain about another - and on and on unless I remove the calculated expression.

Works:

```
INSERT INTO quote_items ( quote_unique, quote_group_a, quote_group_b, unique_product_id, DESCRIPTION, nat_price, markup, sell_price )
SELECT [Forms]![frmQUOTE].[txtQUOTE_NO] AS quote_unique, [Forms]![frmQUOTE].[cmbGROUP_A] AS quote_group_a, [Forms]![frmQUOTE].[txtGROUP_B] AS quote_group_b, ASSY_CHILDREN.UPI, ASSY_CHILDREN.DESCRIPTION, [A - MASTER PRODUCT LIST].[NAT PRICE], [Forms]![frmQUOTE]![txtMU] AS markup, ([NAT PRICE]*[markup])+[NAT PRICE] AS sell_price
FROM [A - MASTER PRODUCT LIST] RIGHT JOIN ASSY_CHILDREN ON [A - MASTER PRODUCT LIST].[UNIQUE PART NO] = ASSY_CHILDREN.PARENT_UPI
WHERE ((([A - MASTER PRODUCT LIST].[UNIQUE PART NO])=[Forms]![frmQUOTE].[cmbPART_TO_ADD]));
```

Doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO quote_items ( quote_unique, quote_group_a, quote_group_b, unique_product_id, DESCRIPTION, QTY, nat_price, markup, sell_price )
SELECT [Forms]![frmQUOTE].[txtQUOTE_NO] AS quote_unique, [Forms]![frmQUOTE].[cmbGROUP_A] AS quote_group_a, [Forms]![frmQUOTE].[txtGROUP_B] AS quote_group_b, ASSY_CHILDREN.UPI, ASSY_CHILDREN.DESCRIPTION, Sum([QTY]*[Forms]![frmQUOTE]![txtQTYTOADD]) AS expr1, [A - MASTER PRODUCT LIST].[NAT PRICE], [Forms]![frmQUOTE]![txtMU] AS markup, ([NAT PRICE]*[markup])+[NAT PRICE] AS sell_price
FROM [A - MASTER PRODUCT LIST] RIGHT JOIN ASSY_CHILDREN ON [A - MASTER PRODUCT LIST].[UNIQUE PART NO] = ASSY_CHILDREN.PARENT_UPI
WHERE ((([A - MASTER PRODUCT LIST].[UNIQUE PART NO])=[Forms]![frmQUOTE].[cmbPART_TO_ADD]));
```

The expression added:

```
expr1: Sum([QTY]*[Forms]![frmQUOTE]![txtQTYTOADD])
```

Wierd thing is it complains that UPI is not part of an aggregate, but returns UPI just fine if this calculated expression is removed (which has nothing to do with UPI)

Comment: Whenever you use aggregate functions, you *must* define grouping criteria (`GROUP BY field1, field2, ...`); that's the reason your query doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: Start by simply getting rid of the `Sum()` and using...

```
expr1: [QTY]*[Forms]![frmQUOTE]![txtQTYTOADD]
```

...or maybe just...

```
expr1: [Forms]![frmQUOTE]![txtQTYTOADD]
```

Test your code and see if it gives you the results you desire. If not, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16203529/edit) your question to show us some representative sample data and an example of what you want to achieve.